# Return an image in Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, image-resizing

I'm trying to load an image from web then compress it with given dimensions and then again return in the response .

```
     public Image getImage(String id) {
        URL url = new URL(id);
        BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(url);

        BufferedImage resizedImg = Scalr.resize(bImage, Scalr.Method.QUALITY, targetWidth, targetHeight);

        Image img =  bufferedImagetoImage(resizedImg);

        return img;}
```

But instead of getting image in response getting this below

```
  "mediaWhitePoint": [
                        0.95014954,
                        1.0,
                        1.0882568
                    ],
                    "matrix": [
                        [
                            0.43585205,
                            0.3853302,
                            0.14302063
                        ],
                        [
                            0.22238159,
                            0.717041,
                            0.06059265
                        ],
                        [
                            0.013916016,
                            0.09713745,
                            0.71383667
                        ]
                    ],
                    "majorVersion": 2,
                    "minorVersion": 48,
                    "data": "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
```

Comment: If the image size is small enough, you can try Base64 to encode the image as a string and put it into json string, after converting it into byte array []. `ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`, `ImageIO.write(resizedImg, "png", byteArrayOutputStream());`, `String imgBase64Str = java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning the image directly. You need to send as byte[].

Please read this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file